# How to wait for a stream to finish writing to a file before reading it

Tags: c#

My code is pretty simple; it uses a StringBuilder and a FileStream to write data to a text file and then [optionally] opens the text file for viewing:

```
public async Task ExportData(data)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine(BuildStringFromData());

    var dir = $@"C:\Ortund\xExports\{DateTime.Now.Date.ToString
        ("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}";
    var fullPath = $@"{dir}\{filename}.txt";

    var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
    await stream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

    if (MessageBox.Show("Open the file?", "Open?", MessageBoxButton.YesNo)
        == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fullPath);
    }
}
```

I awaited the write operation in the file stream thinking this would pause execution of this particular method until all the bytes had been written but that isn't what's happening.

What's happening is that the prompt to open the file is coming up immediately and when I open it, its blank. Notepad++ only informs me a few seconds later that changes have been made to the file and asks me if I want to reload it whereupon I see the data that was exported.

How can I make execution wait until the file data is completely written before asking the user to open the file?

Comment: Call `Write()` method instead of `WriteAsync()`.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn I tried that first; behavior was no different

Comment: Then, you need to close the stream...

Comment: Close stream before opening file to flush all buffers (preferrably by wraping whole thing into `using (var stream = new FileStream(...))`. If for whatever reason you don't want to close - call `await stream.FlushAsync()`

Answer (score 1):

I overlooked the obvious on this one...

As per comment on the question by @Evk, I put the FileStream into a `using` block, but I also moved it to a new method which takes the data and file path as parameters:

```
private async Task WriteDataToFile(List<ViewModel> data, string path)
{
    using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        // Loop through the data and build the string.

        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
        await fs.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
}
```

The using closes the FileStream which is what I overlooked.

Comment: It would also help to have the fs.Close() at the end in order to finalize the stream operation.

Comment: I've upped your OP and your answer. Just what I was looking for, for hours thinking what the hell is locking my filestream... cheers